# Drag and drop Unity

Tags: c#, unity-5, drag-n-drop

Estou tentando desenvolver um simples game Android na Unity, com função de arrastar e soltar objetos.

Usei o seguinte método para pegar o objeto:

```
public void drag(){
    transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
}
```

Problema: está aceitando toques simultâneo na tela e quero que aceite apenas um toque por vez

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2):

Como você está desenvolvendo para o android, pode tratar os touches separadamente, assim:

```
Touch myTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);

    Touch[] myTouches = Input.touches;
    for(int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        //faca algo com cada touch
    }
```

Se no seu caso só interessa o primeiro input, basta utilizar o index 0 no vetor myTouches.